# Remove Git submodule from branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules

Is there a posssiblity to have a submodule on one branch and not to have it on another? Is it possible to remove a submodule on a specific branch but to have it on other branches? Or add a submodule to experimental branch only.

Answer (score 2):

Your submodules are defined by your .gitmodules file, which is just another file in your repository, version like everything else. So if you change it in a branch, it's changed. Thus, all your questions can be answered 'yes'.